# Android Kotlin Firestore Timestamp Range Query

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

currently, I'm trying to query some Timestamp data from my application.
The document has a "date" field (Timestamp) inside it, I would like to get data that fulfill the given date range (after and before) from user input.

After some research, some suggest that I use Date as parameters for whereGreaterThan() and whereLessThan(), but the query seems to always return no data.

Here's the document structure

[image]

Here is my current query:

```
val startDate = Date(2020, 5, 1)
val endDate = Date(2020, 8, 1)

val resultList = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("run")
        .whereGreaterThan("date", startDate)
        .whereLessThan("date", endDate)
        .get()
```

The query should return data that has dates between "startDate" and "endDate"

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what **exactly** you think this query should return.  We can't see your database, so we don't know what to expect.  It would be helpful if you show the specific data.

Comment: @DougStevenson edited

Comment: We can't see that the document is actually in the "run" collection as you are querying now.  You might also want to show the code that handles the query results.  What you're showing now is just how you build a Query object.  It doesn't actually query the database.